# How do you make Dojo BusyButton properties persist after the cancel method is invoked?

Tags: dojo

How do you make Dojo BusyButton properties persist after the cancel method is invoked?

In my parent class, I create a button like this.

```
this.saveButton = new dojox.form.BusyButton({
    'iconClass' : "dijitIconSave"
    , 'label': 'Save'
    , 'busyLabel': 'Saving...'
    , 'timeout': 30000
})
```

Then in my child class, I change some properties.

```
this.saveButton.set('label', 'Add');
this.saveButton.set('busyLabel', 'Adding...');
this.saveButton.set('timeout', 2000);
```

The button looks like this:

[image]

Great. But after I run `this.saveButton.cancel();`

The button reverts to:

[image]

Why aren't the properties that I've set persist beyond `this.saveButton.cancel()`?

What's the best way to stop the busy animation without resetting the `BusyButton` properties to their original values?

**UPDATE**:

I had a look at the BusyButton code and the `cancel` method sets the label by running `this.setLabel(this._label);`. Shouldn't that be `this.setLabel(this.label);`? I don't like accessing private variables but for now this is my workaround.

```
this.saveButton.set({
    _label: 'Add'
    , label: 'Add'
    , busyLabel: 'Adding...'
    , timeout: 5000
})
```

Is this a Dojo bug or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known bug. See http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/10644

Comment: Yes, thank you. Two years old with a patch and a test. It's surprising and frustrating to see these patches like this not accepted by upstream.

Comment: I agree... I guess your patch works I guess anyway... maybie you can add a message to the ticket to wake it up ;-)